# to click on a partially visible webelement in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application I am not able to click on a partially visible check box, I even tried to do the same with javascript(scrool and click) and mouse hover actions, could any one find me a solution for the same?

Comment: Could you please put up your code here?

Comment: g_element=g_driver.findElement(g_util.getObject("./ObjectRepository/"+objfile+".xml", objfile, office, "xpath"));                                                         /*Here I am identifying the web element with a function,and it is  running in a loop, it perfectly runs for other  check boxes, except the one partially visible */                                          
                             JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)g_driver;
                                                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", g_element);

Comment: Please don't post code or HTML in the comments. Edit your question and add the code and HTML there, properly formatted.

Comment: What is a partially visible check box? It's either visible or not. Please add some details to the question to make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
WebElement g_element=g_driver.findElement(g_util.getObject("./ObjectRep‌​ository/"+objfile+".‌​xml", objfile, office, "xpath"));
Webdriverwait wait = new Webdriverwait(driver,10)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator);
if(!elementChkBox.isSelected()) {
    checkbox.click();
}
```

Comment: Asking OP to try something is not an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.